# SQL change date formats inside a string

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, date

I would like to convert a string containing dates in SQL select from Oracle 11g database.

Original string (CLOB) example:

```
"1.12.2011 - event 1
 2.2.2012 - event 2
 13.3.2012 - event 44"
```

Desired output:

```
"20111201 - event 1
 20120202 - event 2
 20120313 - event 44"
```

Is there a better (faster) way than using 4 separate replacements?

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(my_string,
'(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(20\d\d)', '\3\2\1'),
'(\d\d)\.(\d)\.(20\d\d)', '\30\2\1'),
'(\d)\.(\d\d)\.(20\d\d)', '\3\20\1'),
'(\d)\.(\d)\.(20\d\d)', '\30\20\1')
```

Comment: why are dates in strings?  Kinda hard to use that way

Comment: @tbone i did not design the database - but i guess it was easier to put arbitrary number of dates into one string than to create a new table in already large database with a lot of schemes when it was intendet for human reading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no better options (both correct and readable) with better performance - or if there are, no one cares..

Answer (score 1):

Especially if you're using clobs you have to be careful unless you're certain of the data in there.

However, if your clob only looks like that then you need three`regexp_replace` in order for this to work; it'll also be much more dynamic. Just explicitly specify digits using `[[:digit:]]` then specify a minimum and maximum number of times these digits could be there using `{1,2}`.

Then the following would work:

```
select regexp_replace( 
          regexp_replace( 
             regexp_replace( my_string
                           , '([[:digit:]]{1,2})\.([[:digit:]]{1,2})\.(20[[:digit:]]{2})'
                           , '\3-\2-\1')
                        , '-([[:digit:]]{1}(-|$))'
                        , '0\1' )
                     , ('-')
                     , '')
  from dual
```

This means:

- match *( group 1 )* 1 or 2 digits
- match a full stop.
- match *( group 2 )* 1 or 2 digits
- match a full stop
- match *( group 3 )* 20 + 2 digits.

Then take out only groups 1, 2 and 3, i.e. ignoring the full stops and return then in the order 3, 2, 1 padded with a hyphen

Then replace any `[digit]` that is followed by either a hyphen or the end of the string, i.e. the number of digits is only 1 with `-0[digit]`.

Lastly replace all the hyphens.

Separately from that I agree with [tbone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534120/tbone). It would make a lot more sense to store this data in a separate table `(event_id number, event_date date)`. Any string transformations are easy with no chance of getting it wrong, unlike in this situation, and the data is easy to query and compare.

Comment: thanks for a good idea,, however for `11.10.2011` it would return `2011010011` - all hyphens followed by 2 digits are followed by a single digit in the first place

Comment: now it's almost ok,, just the last digit is never followed by the end of the string - it is followed by a space as in the examle ;)) and i would have to use a different temp character from a hyphen, because i don't want to replace all hyphens by empty string

Comment: @deathApril, I tried yesterday to come up with something better ( for a few minutes ) .... but there's always a problem... ( i.e. I failed miserably :-) ), which is why regular expressions are evil and a normalised database is the way to go...

Comment: thanks for your efforts anyway ;) at least there are reqexes in oracle, i can't imagine implementing it in DB2 (using a select that is)

Comment: BTW - i did not accept because it is not working - from `5.3.2012` it creates `2012035` instead of `20120305` :(

Answer (score 0):

i prefer a 2-level regexp_replace for date part:

```
select regexp_replace(
           regexp_replace( my_string,
               '([[:digit:]]{1,2})\.([[:digit:]]{1,2})\.(20[[:digit:]]{2})',
               '\3-0\2-0\1' ),
           '(20[[:digit:]]{2})-0?([[:digit:]]{2})-0?([[:digit:]]{2})',
           '\3\2\1' )
from dual;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/11934/0)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try doing:

```
select to_char(to_date('13.3.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY'),'YYYYMMDD') from dual;
```

Comment: -1 how would i get '13.3.2011' from my string? how can conversion of all the dates in my string and then concatenate them all back together be faster than `regexp_replace`?